# How do I get LocationManager.addNmeaListener() to work?

Tags: android-gps

Here are the relevant parts of my code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements SensorEventListener, OnNmeaMessageListener {

    private LocationManager m_locationManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ac = this;
        m_locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
    }
...
    protected void onResume() {
    ...
        if (m_locationManager != null) {
            m_gpsSensor = new SensorView(this);
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
m_locationManager.addNmeaListener(getMainExecutor(), this);
                } else {
                    // no-op in later versions
                    m_locationManager.addNmeaListener(this);
                }
                m_gpsSensor.lineBreak("gps: ", "no messages yet");
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
                m_gpsSensor.lineBreak("gps: ", getString(R.string.permissiondenied));
            }
            topLayout.addView(m_gpsSensor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNmeaMessage(String message, long timestamp) {
        long nanos = timestamp * 1000000;
        if (nanos > m_gpsSensor.lastNanos + UPDATE_NANOS) {
            m_gpsSensor.lastNanos = nanos;
            m_gpsSensor.lineBreak("gps: ", message);
        }
    }
}
```

`onNmeaMessage` is never called (`lastNanos` is initialised to zero) and `m_gpsSensor` (a subclass of `View`) displays "no messages yet". My device does have GPS, and the app has permission to access it (otherwise it would display "Permission denied"), and GPS does work, because it can see satellites and get a fix with [Satstat](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.vonglasow.michael.satstat/)

I tried
`addNmeaListener (OnNmeaMessageListener listener, Handler handler)`
which doesn't work either. `m_locationManager` isn't null, because in that case it wouldn't display anything at all.

The device is a Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra 5G running Android 12.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `addNmeaListener` doesn't start the GPS, and there doesn't seem to be an explicit call to do so. You have to call one of the `requestLocationUpdates` variants.